# Gremlin - Vertex Path

Tags: node.js, graph, gremlin, graph-databases, vertex

I have data in graph database (Gremlin) and have vertex with their edges.
For example :

```
a-\>b-\>c-\>d-\>e
f-\>d-\>e
```

I am accessing gremlin in node js project. When i am returning the vertex, is there any way i can get the location/path of the vertex along with it?
Like : If vertex e is returned then path should return :

```
\[a-\>b-\>c-\>d-\>e,f-\>d-\>e\]
```

I tried all sort of queries and ended up with below query which returns the path between 2 vertex :

```
await g.V().hasLabel(\<vertex1\>).repeat(__.timeLimit(20).out()).until(__.hasLabel(\<vertex2\>)).path().by(\<propertyname\>).toList();
```

Above query takes 20 ms for each return and there are more than 20 vertex which i want to search path for.

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the `timeLimit`. It's going to limit how far the query can progress. It's probably too limiting for you case. I only ever use `timeLimit` in very special cases. It has the semantics of "do the best you can".